# ie9 animate rotate How to use

Tags: jquery, animation

```
.leaf_01 { 
     top:-5px;
     left:-13px;
     animation: swing ease-in-out 1.6s infinite alternate;  
     transform-origin: center -20px;
}

@keyframes swing {
     0% { transform: rotate(3deg); } 
     100% { transform: rotate(-3deg); }
}
```

i can speak english very well sorry

I am using

ie9 animation no support, It does not work -ms- same here.

so jquery animate Try to use It's not good

```
$(".leaf_01").css("transform","rotate(-3deg)");
```

Like this Available but

leaf continue shaking shape  need

animate How to use please.....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like below

```
$(".leaf_01").css({
           '-moz-transform':'rotate(-3deg)',
          '-webkit-transform':'rotate(-3deg)',
          '-o-transform':'rotate(-3deg),
          '-ms-transform':'rotate(-3deg)',
          'transform': 'rotate(-3deg)'
 });
```

Comment: rotate(3deg)  rotate (-3deg) 
Infinite repeat  i need..

@keyframes swing {0% { transform: rotate(3deg); } 100% { transform: rotate(-3deg); }}

css > jquery animate need